# Android Timetable schedule notification and update system

Tags: android, database, timetable, time-tracking

I would be very interested in making a train timetable that displays train1, train2, train3 arriving at a certain stop. So say the timetable is as follows:

Stop-----Train 1-----Train 2----Train 3

118------12.00--------11.15-----10.30

118------12.30--------11.48-----11.00

118------13.05--------12.20-----11.30

118------13.35--------13.25-----12.00

118------14.10--------14.25-----12.30

How would you display in realtime with an android service that uses the current time and will display the minutes left till the next train arriving at 118 for each train constantly and always in the background. So it would look something like this:

Stop 118

Current time: 11.01

Train 1 Arriving 59mins
Train 2 Arriving 14mins
Train 3 Arriving Due

I imagine you would first have to create a data structure to hold all the trains and their times and somehow match those times to the current time?

Can anyone shed any light as to which is the best way to do this...

Comment: It was so unnecessary to negative rep me for asking a valid question. There aren't that many resources on the web for someone starting out making a database structure for android and there are many methods, I simply posted the question at hand thoroughly to get some input on the best form to tackle the query. I'm sure there are plenty of users that have done something similar to this, which is why I posted... Can we remain on topic please.

Comment: Its a shame, the time you spent writing these two comments you could have probably given me some help that would have benefited others on  the site and my project. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is your best bet.

Comment: I see, so some kind of Handler loop to send messages to the activity. Can you use the handler to access an sqlite database?

Comment: Yeah, if you wanted to post a `Runnable` that accessed a database, you could do that, although AsyncTasks are also a good place for such work. The specific advantage to a Handler in the case you mentioned is that you can post a `Runnable` to execute at a given time (see `postAtTime` in the `Handler` reference).